# Access to cloud foundry filesystem (like FTP)?

Tags: ssh, filesystems, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-tools

I have some cloud foundry nodejs apps in IBM Cloud (Bluemix), and facing some issues with temp folders. It'd be easier if I can access directly to app folders (like my .tmp) to debug what's saving there. I can only think in SSH, but I prefer a visual tool or connected service. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You can use graphical tools to browse the files by utilizing **scp** or **sftp**. I use FileZilla to browser the files. [Instructions for accessing the files are similar to all Cloud Foundry providers, including IBM Cloud](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html):

1. I logged in to IBM Cloud using the CLI: `ibmcloud login`
2. Next, set the org and space: `ibmcloud target --cf`
3. Obtain the GUID for the app: `ibmcloud cf app YOURAPP --guid`
4. Look for the ssh endpoint: `ibmcloud cf curl /v2/info`
5. Issue a onetime password for ssh access: `ibmcloud cf ssh-code`

With that, use a username like **cf:theGUIDfrom3/0** (0 could be another number depending on how many instances you have) and the onetime password to log in. The host is the one listed as **app_ssh_endpoint** at the shown port. You likely need to prefix it with the protocol, e.g., **sftp://**.